# Edit after rollback should notify backroller/rollbacker

Tags: feature-request, rollbacks

If one initiates a rollback on another's question, then obviously to undo an invalid edit. Subsequent edits may again be invalid as the following examples show.

Yesterday I did three rollbacks for complete deletes on the following questions. Two of them were again modified to change the question and render answers meaningless.

- [Implement my own maplist in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291895/implement-my-own-maplist-in-prolog) (1 rollback)
- [Prolog - Multiply a list with an element results with a weird tail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291529/prolog-multiply-a-list-with-an-element-results-with-a-weird-tail) (2 rollbacks)
- [Prolog - get the factors for a given number doesn't stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273559/prolog-get-the-factors-for-a-given-number-doesnt-stop) (2 rollbacks)

A notification about an edit after the first rollback would help to find such cases.

Or ... is there another way to handle these?

Comment: No, looks like an overkill. Those cases are rare enough, just keep an eye over the post and maybe add to favorites. If it happens again and again flag for moderator attention, they can lock the post and/or warn the user.

Comment: @Sha: And the only way to keep an eye on it is via favourites. Yes?

Comment: Favorites or just keep open tab and refresh it sometimes. :)

Comment: This seems likely to encourage edit wars.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not your responsibility to watch over other users' posts. If you run into a problem and can fix it - good. If there is another problem later, surely someone else will notice and fix or reject that edit.

I have made lots (thousands) of edits and edit reviews, and would absolutely not like to be alerted every time there is another change to one of those posts.

Comment: I did not ask to be informed about subsequent edits of my edits. In that case it is quite safe to assume that both have the same intention to improve a post. What I suggested was to be informed about edits after rollbacks. In that situation one cannot assume that the original writer has good intentions to improve the post.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the OP is informed in the `Activity` tab in his user profile page.  You can filter these using the `Revisions` button.

It should be pretty simple to implement having any editors notified of the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather not be notified when an edit I did was rolled back; I would probably be the last person who can judge about the rollback being correct.

I don't see also why the user who edited the question should be notified of the rollback, and change the question again, when there are many users who can notice the wrong edit, and change the question to a better revision.
If the user replaces the question text with total no-sense, somebody else will notice that, and rollback the question to the previous revision. If the OP keeps changing back the question, moderators are notified of a possible edit war, and they would do the necessary to block that; for example, they can temporary lock the question.

Comment: It seems you are answering to a different situation.

Comment: It doesn't seem so: You are talking of edits you did to somebody else's question, for which the OP rolled back the question, and removed your edit.

Comment: That is a misunderstanding of your side! [please look at this history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14273559/revisions) Revision 4: I did a rollback of a complete vandalism since the question was replaced by ....... Then an important part of the question was deleted, and I rolled that back again.

Comment: ... and the only persons to understand that the second edit is invalid (per se) are persons who answered. So the destructive edit would go unnoticed otherwise. The belief that any such edit would be detected as @BoPersson suggests, is unrealistic

Comment: Let's be clear: I understand you are talking of self-vandalism done from another user which you corrected. What I am saying is that it doesn't need to be you who corrects the second vandalism (removing the code shown from the question). The question is bumped on the front page when it is edited, and other users can see how it has been edited.

Comment: When a question bumps up all its history is not directly visible. So maybe it would make sense instead to somehow indicate that there was a rollback before?

Comment: When a question is bumped, who edited/added a new answer, or edited the question is visible. Once you look at the question, you see which posts was edited, and understand if it was created, or edited. At that point you can the revisions of that post.